# [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds is changing its size at startup on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I put breakpoint in

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

and I put break point in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

I checked `bounds` twice and got different size.

```
(lldb) po [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 375, height = 667))

(lldb) po [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 568, height = 320))
```

What may change it? Is it some comparability mode with iPhone 5 ?

Also all graphics looks pixelated on iPhone 6 like on non retina screen. But iPhone 5 looks very good.

It is GL app and it loads high res images.

Something switches app in glitchy mode.

Any ideas what may force that mode on iPhone 6 in that mode?

iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 both run same iOS 10.2.1

Comment: post an screenshot..

Comment: Did you remove LaunchScreen.storyboard by chance? This will affect the size of the screen the app occupies for newer iOS. Try creating a simple one window project, remove the LaunchScreen reference from Info.plist and see if the problem replicates.

Answer (score 1):

The most probably you have designed the view in IB or storyboard. The first bounds represents bounds of the view in storyboard. The second on the real device after reaching viewDidAppear with respect to the orientation.